# Google geocodes api vs storing it myself

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

Is it worth to pay for geocoding API? Google will start billing when I exceed the limit, it's not much to pay but is there any advantage using it over storing my own geocodes like importing the dump from http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/ to my own database and use that.

You could say uptime, but if my service is down then it wouldn't matter if I use google api or my own api for geocoding. What would you say?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking if your idea regarding storing data in your database is compatible with Google Maps API Terms of Service. Particularly,  with the section 10.5 (d) of the ToS that reads:

> **No caching or storage.** You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage:
>
> - is temporary (and in no event more than 30 calendar days);
> - is secure;
> - does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
> - does not modify attribution in any way.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#section_10_5